# partition icons disappeared after installing windows 7.

Tags: windows-7, macos, mac, partitioning

I installed windows 7 on macbookPro OS X Lion. The mac partition doesn't appear in startup menu anymore and windows 7 boots automatically. The option/alt key only brings up an option for windows. The X key doesn't boot mac either.

In windows,Disk manager has only two volumes: an unallocated volume and a windows local disk(C) volume.

Answer (score 0):

Windows will never recognize anthers S.O in the disk manager at least out of windows family, its sounds to me you have the mac os at first and after that you installed windows SO so windows imposed his grub, this happen in linux too, you need to recreate the grub again or "
"boot".